# Run Time error : 5 invalid procedure call or argument in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub btnsubmit_Click()

Dim Msg As String
Dim pos1 As Integer
Dim pos2 As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim flag As Integer
Dim telphno    

Msg = TextBox1.Value
pos1 = 1
pos2 = 1

flag = 0

Do While pos1 < Len(Msg)

    pos1 = InStr(pos1, Msg, "[")
    If flag = 0 Then
        pos2 = InStr(pos2, Msg, "]")
    End If

    If pos2 - pos1 < 5 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = Mid(Msg, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)        
        Count = 0

        'Loop through the entire string
        For i = pos2 To Len(Msg)

            'Check to see if the character is a numeric one
            If IsNumeric(Mid(Msg, i, 1)) Then

                'Add it to the answer
                telphno = telphno + Mid(Msg, i, 1)
                Count = Count + 1                    

                'Check to see if we have reached 10 digits
                If Count = 10 Then Exit For                        

            Else
                telphno = ""
                Count = 0                
            End If

        Next i

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = telphno
        flag = 0
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        pos1 = pos2 + 1
        pos2 = pos1
        telphno = ""        
    Else
        flag = 1
        pos1 = pos1 + 1            
  End If

Loop

End Sub
```

[image: I am getting error on using MID function highlighted in yellow.]

I am trying to fetch the characters between "[" and "]" in my string but MID function is giving me error. Please help me to fix this problem.

After finding the Characters between "[" and "]" I am looking for nearest 10 digit number. I am taking the string through TextBox (User Input).
And Printing the output on Excel Sheet.

For ex-

```
[A22]1239163332bcfhds[B23]6453jhddf2784637281ajdnjda[C33]dksamkd1288776655
```

For the above string. It should give -

```
A22 1239163332  
B23 2784637281
C33 1288776655
```

Input 2 -

`@ﬁJaeasaﬁGpaaaaod [A1] # 42, 5532 23156 “63’ 8:355 dedmaa @656 663336, {33538365. sail & as" 53666 wee—9008799499. @dﬁs.ée.maae06 [A2] S/O éegddad mweeﬁ @dﬁE aaseaeﬁ mwaossae We" ﬂees?) all 359% as" ﬁdee, wee—9886557596.
$036903: WI 29365 amass @aoﬂae maﬁa] (me) sail was?“ asllmairid’, aha—9945173528. @6066 60333305 2:056. [A4] £06333 messes $6503.91:
33:12:05 mews. 8.133133% a?" aiding as" mamas.
aha-9886444737. [50%. memergﬁos, [A5] mew 89335365 mamas.
mama. aan wage, as" eagdade, diam—9731742667. eaaiodﬁaas. [A6]
ge Wagﬁegd mwaoﬁsae maﬁa) £3966.maﬁa).sail mg"), as" mairiﬁ, met—9986611558. @8396 30653236 [A7] ﬂeas $839395 ﬂeas# 4138/38, Sgéegd 33905:,623 ﬁnaSeag soomrf,ao.&.&.‘w’ea§ss,$3913.29. ﬁdeaas 6:312:36,anaemia.all dog as" macaw-36,mom—9448166197.mamas 8985305 [A8192 ageng mews sambaaadeﬁaeﬁéﬁeo.all adswsg, all warm,dam—9945363102.@69535 games [A9]amasssesame@06.ao.&.dsaec56maisaﬁd.aall $33.19 as" mamrid’,wag—9844644272.as.demam] 33mmadésada.Gall 836%62, as" $3668,
wee:—8.839%:ngge [imam meme $36033“ﬂaccid weave.mweaﬁd.all 623; as" maiarid,dam—9481161243.agodaé.8.ao.129330556 agaossae53%;.a?" & as" 5365366,mez—990187114-1.8884232296@2353e65@55.@05.9:330:36 @9033“we ems aim-.1353,swag.all 666663, as" maladdwag—8123565686.gang-56$60506 masses ﬁaoﬁaemaﬁﬂeas mews,swag.all 8665383, as" mdwﬁd
aha—9845781954.[A10][A11][A12][A13][A14]$63535 3:633:56 [A15]@663 aaaaaeﬁ SawadJaeawe: aa£eas€ mews,{3368366.sail 6.9% all 0369966,dam—9945707587eaoadﬁ mesmereaa’cﬁwsl6:36:38 agaoisaeﬁasﬁewéédaall 303:3, as" 03653613,dam-9900436152.$830335eiedaﬁ $885366 Qawaeeiapﬂsaecss,asasdne.aall wipe, as" 53566,Elma—9448218974.$69836 memergﬁos [A18]# 167,“&oa5555”15’ 2:336, 63:: @55,deg-353255 9:355 acme-3%,massariﬁ.aall 3.3.333 as” nae-36386,WEE—9342495800.@%§ mewaergﬁcs [A19]# 794/8 oomﬁeo.modes mews,65366666.all 6333 as" mwwﬁ'ﬁ,dam—9945434802.$830535 Meme®$cs [A20]@30335 masses Mathewsmandaoddwsg.sail ﬁne]; as" 53538363,met-9980170633.@506 memergaos903361103: $358365 Saaawsae3536333.Ball 36335623, as" $368966,Wei-9972675782[A17] [A21]`

Expected Ouput -

A1 9008799499
A2 9886557596
A4 9886444737
A5 9731742667
A6 9986611558
A7 9448166197
and so on till
A20 9980170633

Comment: upload your code as code so we can use it (and not as as image)

Comment: I would guess that `pos2` is zero when it crashed - post your code and we can help you work out what is wrong.

Comment: also, it can shorten the debug time if you let us know what value you entered in your `TextBox1` when you got this error

Comment: Shai Rado and YowE3K, Please let me know if you need any other information to debug this problem.

Comment: @PrasoonPandey see my answer and code suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is "screaming" for the use of `RegEx` , see code below (explantion inside code comments).

***Sub btnsubmit* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnsubmit_Click()

Dim Msg As String
Dim pos1 As Integer
Dim pos2 As Integer
Dim posDelta As Integer
Dim telphno
Dim i As Integer

' added these 2 variables
Dim insideBrackets As String
Dim telphnoPos As Integer

TextBox1.Value = Sheets("sheet2").Range("H5").Value
Msg = TextBox1.Value

pos1 = 1
pos2 = 1

' loop while Msg still no emptied out
Do While (Msg) <> ""
    TextBox1.Value = Msg
    Debug.Print Len(Msg)

    pos1 = InStr(Msg, "[")
    pos2 = InStr(Msg, "]")

    ' find number of characters between "[" and "]"
    posDelta = pos2 - pos1

    Select Case posDelta
        Case Is < 0  ' only "]" found , and no "["
            Msg = Right(Msg, Len(Msg) - pos2)

        Case 3, 4 ' could be A# , or A##
            insideBrackets = Mid(Msg, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)

            telphno = "" ' reset value
            telphnoPos = 0

            Msg = Right(Msg, Len(Msg) - pos2)

            ' call function with Regex to find first 10 digits in string
            telphno = GetFirstTenDigits(Msg)

            ' find position of first 10 digits inside the string
            If telphno <> "" Then telphnoPos = InStr(Msg, telphno)

            ' successfult 10-digit resulted from RegEx
            If telphnoPos > 0 Then
                ActiveCell.Value = insideBrackets
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = telphno

                ' remove characters from string that were extracted to the cells
                Msg = Right(Msg, Len(Msg) - (telphnoPos + 10 - 1))
                insideBrackets = "" ' reset value

                ' advance 1 row
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
                Msg = "" ' no 10 digits ccurrences left
            End If

        Case Is > 4
            Msg = Right(Msg, Len(Msg) - pos1)

    End Select
Loop

End Sub

***Function GetFirstTenDigits* Code** (uses the `Regex` object)

Function GetFirstTenDigits(byMixedString As String) As String

' this function uses the RegEx to find all numeric characters insde the passed string
' then it searches for the first occorunce that the number of digits = 10 ,
' and returns it to the calling Sub

    Dim RegEx As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\d+)" ' Match any set of digits
    End With

    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(byMixedString)

    For Each Match In Matches
        If Len(Match) = 10 Then
            ' return the first match of 10 digits
            GetFirstTenDigits = Match
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Match

End Function
```

Comment: for what ? what input do you want to test ? I have not included in my code errors hanlding, there are infinte options for error to handle.

Comment: Getting the same error for this input - ésaeas meme. [A671

8353698 mamas aoﬁm

ﬂocks mews, 03338366.
as" =3:an as" maisedd,
aha—9731432004.

ﬁsaeas 33.8). [A681
aesofnge imam Egaoﬁsae

eadrboa.

Ball domais as" age-3,

wee—9449343829.
6353 $335366 aoﬂwe [A69]

35393389655 ﬁoéﬁg,
8:55 50135 theme,

mesa.

as" dam,

aha—9448640505.

 [A70]
533 gasses agaoisae & aeaoisae
6355306 $3665, 853333933,

65365366.
an 35:33 as" mwadﬁ,
aha—8495819232.

8535 meme 536 [A71]
ﬁance 92% 9:33:33,
T.M. 853ech

may. 577217

as" maiseﬁd,

aha—9141629909.

Comment: The thing is your code is solving the problem for that input but not for the above input. Getting the same runtime error on same line.

Comment: can you take the above inputs, and edit your your post with them ? try to put each input in a row, and what is the expected output . I can't read what you have above correctly

Comment: @PrasoonPandey copy edited code (almost entire new code) and test

Comment: @PrasoonPandey so nothing ? no feedback from you ?

Comment: Getting the same error on line [insideBrackets = Mid(Msg, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)]

Comment: @PrasoonPandey trying what text string ? I ran you Loooon string from aobve and I got the desried result. are you sure you copied this exact text ?

Comment: @ShadiRao I restarted my system and now it is working fine. Thank you so much for your help. Can you tell me why exactly i was getting that error by comparing your code with my original code ?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is occurring because you are not exiting the loop when there are no more `[...]` pairs remaining.

If you change

```
pos1 = InStr(pos1, Msg, "[")
```

to have the following code immediately after it, I think your problems will go away:

```
If pos1 = 0 Then
    Exit Do
End If
```

---

Your calculation of `pos2` should also be changed from

```
pos2 = InStr(pos2, Msg, "]")
```

to

```
pos2 = InStr(pos1, Msg, "]")
```

This will ensure that you are picking up the location of the first `]` after the current `[`.

---

After those two changes, your code correctly processes both of the examples now given in your question ... except for writing out records for the trailing `[A17]` and `[A21]` in the second example - I'm not sure whether you really want them ignored, or whether your second example was truncated partway through the source data.